# django- deploy with mod_wsgi css not showing

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am using libapache2-mod_wsgi for deploying my django app. I wrote httpd.conf as follows:

```
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/similarkind/similarkind/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/similarkind/similarkind/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/similarkind/similarkind/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/similarkind:/home/ubuntu/pysushu/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Directory /home/ubuntu/similarkind/similarkind>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Well my app is working just fine but css and javascript is not showing up.
I have my css and js in static folder. Also my directory structure for app looks like

```
/similarkind
    /static
        /foundation-3
            /stylesheets
            /js
        /jquery-ui
            /css
            /js
```

Can anyone tell what thing am I missing?

Comment: Do you truly mean 'mysite' where as else where you use 'similarkind'?

Comment: actually, i used similarkind, not mysite. Sorry my mistake :)

Comment: But what are all the paths before that as well, just to make absolutely sure we can see the full absolute path. Also check what all the file/directory permissions are. Can the user Apache runs as even read the stuff there. Try and go directly to a URL for a static file, what happens?

Comment: What do you see in the apache log ? If you type directly the url of one of the js or css in the address bar of the browser what is the error code displayed by the browser

Comment: Well, I got it working now. I had to change the permission for my css files to 644. thanks for your time mate. :)

Comment: It's not explicitly mentioned here, but the Alias line should point to the *project*'s /static/ folder, NOT the applications' nor the one where files get uploaded to in your settings.py file (STATIC_ROOT).

That would have helped me with my issue.

Comment: @Sushant Gupta: Also worth mentioning: Be sure they are owned by the apache or www-data user, I didn't need to change the file permissions, so it could be they are owned by root or your own user and cannot be seen by apache *until* you allowed global read permissions.

Comment: @NuclearPeon Ok mate. First of all thanks for your time and help. Actually I have switched to Node server long ago. I am no more using Django and Apache, but nonetheless I appreciate your concern :)